# Jade iteration to HTML table

Tags: html, iteration, pug

How can I add the price array to the second 'td' tag in Jade? I would like it to be iteration. Is it possible?

```
- var item = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
- var price = ['40', '90', '140']

table.pricetable
    thead
        tr
            th item
            th price
    tbody
        each a in item
            tr
                td #{a}
                td ???
```

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are directly related:

```
- var item = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
- var price = ['40', '90', '140']

table.pricetable
    thead
        tr
            th item
            th price
    tbody
        each a, index in item
            tr
                td #{a}
                td #{price[index]}
```

However, a much better approach would be to use an array of objects, instead of two separate arrays:

```
- var items = [{item: 'Item1', price: 40}, {item: 'Item2', price: 90}, {item: 'Item3', price: 140}]

table.pricetable
    thead
        tr
            th item
            th price
    tbody
        each a in item
            tr
                td #{a.item}
                td #{a.price}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, by also getting the index in the loop:

```
- var item = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
- var price = ['40', '90', '140']

table.pricetable
    thead
        tr
            th item
            th price
    tbody
        each a, index in item
            tr
                td #{a}
                td #{price[index]}
```

This allows you to get the index of the current value you're iterating over, and can be used to access the same position in the other array.

Comment: You beat me by 2 minutes haha